# Chunk filter with NodeJS memoize prevents view refresh in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, view, filter

Im using nodejs memoize to chunk an object in Angularjs (to better use it with bootstrap columns)

```
app.filter('chunk', function() {
   return memoize(chunk);
});
```

and in view:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in groupProjects | chunk:4">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" ng-repeat="item in row">
      {{item.name}}
   </div>
</div>
```

But if i get new data for groupProjects in my controller, thew view is not updated. It updates, if i remove the filter, but not with it.

What causes the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the value of `chunk` is, but assuming it's a function then your code should look like this:

```
app.filter('chunk', memoize(chunk));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why NodeJS should be involved in this but anyway, you can do this by injecting underscore (or lodash) in your app. Notice, we memoize this function to prevent Angular starting infinite amount of digests.

```
app.factory "lodash", ["$window", ($window)->
  $window._
]

#filters
app.filter "chunk", ["lodash", (_)->
  _.memoize _.chunk
]
```